# How can I create menu links to external URLs?

Tags: 8, routes

With my module *MYMODULE* I would like to create external link and place it into `main` menu.
Is it possible to do that in `MYMODULE.links.menu.yml` file or `MYMODULE.routing.yml`?

Something like this???

**mymodule.links.menu.yml**

```
mymodule.googlecom:
  title: 'Google'
  route_name: 'googlecom'
  menu_name: main
```

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
googlecom:
  path: 'http://google.com/'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mymodule.menu_external_link:
  title: 'External link'
  url: 'https://www.drupal.org'
  menu_name: main
  weight: 10
  options:
    attributes:
      target: _blank
      class: my-class
```

Answer (score 4):

routing.yml are routes of your site, so they can not be external.

links.menu.yml are links that point to routes, so they can not be external.

To create external links, you need to create them as a menu link content entity in your hook_install() function.

Something like this:

```
  $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create(array(
      'title' => 'Link title',
      'link' => ['uri' => 'https://www.example.com'],
      'menu_name' => 'navigation',
      'weight' => 0,
      'external' => TRUE,
      'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
    ));
  $menu_link->save();
```